# Conflicting types in variadic function

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'm working with C again after a long time for a project and am trying to get my head around variadic functions. Basically, I want to be able to pass a number of strings to a function.

```
#include<stdarg.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    test_function(2,"test","test2");
    test_function(4,"test3","test4","test5","test6");

    return 0;
}


void test_function(int args, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, args);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<args;i++)
    {
        printf("Argument:%s\n",va_arg(ap, char*));
    }

    va_end(ap);
}
```

I'm getting an error around the test_function - Conflicting types for 'test_function'

Can anyone point me to my error?

Comment: You have no prototype for `test_function`, the compiler is implicitly declaring it as `int test_function()` upon discovery in `main()`. Then it encounters `void test_function(int,...)`. They're not the same.

Comment: Just figured that out! Thanks Whoz!

Comment: Any reason why you wronly use `va_arg(ap, int)` instead of `va_arg(ap, char *)`?

Comment: It was an error in the code because it was changed during the debugging phase I believe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the declaration of `test_function` before using it. You need to include `stdio.h` as well since you are using `printf`.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void test_function(int args, ...);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
```

Comment: Thanks Yu Hao. I have that in my source. Coming back to C after 6 years is going to be a challenge. I've become too used to other high level languages and their comforts.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said put a prototype for `test_function`, also note that in

```
 printf("Argument:%s\n",va_arg(ap, int));
```

you are passing strings to this function (not `int`s), instead use:

```
 printf("Argument:%s\n",va_arg(ap, char *));
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add a prototype for the function, silly me! Just added

```
void test_function (int args, ...);
```

above the main() and it worked.

Comment: This is right. But, as others told you this as well, this your anser didn't add any value here. In turn, you could accept ✓ one of the other answers.

Comment: I couldn't accept an answer for a certain period. I must have forgotten after that.

Comment: Well, that can happen :-)

Answer (score 0):

Either put a prototype for your function  or define it before `main()`.